# Currency conversion from default currency(dollars) to the another currency(dhirams) is happening twice

Tags: orders, invoice, magento-1.6, currency

When i convert currency from the default currency Dollars to another currency AED in currency converter and place an order and try to print the invoice PDF. In invoice it is showing the conversion rate correctly. but when i give print option the price which has already been converted from Dhiram to dollar is again converted into Dhiram. 
    Currency conversion is happening twice in this case. 
[image: This is how my invoice looks]

Conversion is correct but if i print the invoice .Price amount changes from 2271 AED to 8745 AED.

Comment: Any customizations you use regarding currency conversion or PDF invoice creation?

Comment: I'm using ET currency manager for the currency conversion the same error occurs when i use coupon code at the checkout page. When the currency is in dollars( default currency) then it is fine coupon code deduction amount is working fine. When the currency is in AED then same issue double conversion is happening.       FOr example: Product prize = 100AED 
if the coupon percentage is 20%
then the total amount must be 80AED. But 80 AED is again multiplied by 3.65.
so it becomes 292 AED. Because of this the total amount is going in negative value.

Comment: I think 100 AED the system is taking as 100$ and again converting it into AED. Thats y double conversion is taking place.

Comment: Did you get in contact with the ET currency manager support?

Comment: I did mail to the support team. Awaiting for the reply from them.

Comment: Hi, the issue is even when the ET currency manager is disabled. Same error is occuring. Any idea..???